# How to go GWT History, two step back?

Tags: gwt, browser-history

How can i go to GWT History, I'm currently using

```
History.back();
```

It take me it's immediate history. But If i want to go back more than immediate history, what should i do. I called `History.back()` 2 time. But it only called once. I didn't maintained any history tag.

Comment: It works for me to call `History.back();` twice - it takes me two tags back in the history. Can you provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: What about using JS `window.history.go(-2)`? This could be put in a JSNI and is perhaps sufficient in your case?